# Need security pattern to unlock my new blu tablet

Tags: security, tablet, sim-unlocking

I received a brand new BLU tablet and someone has already put a security pattern on it to unlock it. How do I unlock it?

Comment: If it already has a pattern lock then it can't be brand new. Also if it has a pattern it is most likely also bound to a Google account which means even after a factory reset you would run into the factory reset protection which asks for the Google password of the account last assigned with the device. As you don't have that password that will block you from using the device.

Answer (score 1):

Return the tablet.

It isn't new, if someone has put a lock pattern on it. This could be carelessness by the supplier, sending out a tablet that isn't new, or it could be fraud by one of their staff. In any case, it is *not your problem*, but theirs.

ETA: After looking at BLU Products' [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLU_Products), I'd demand a refund, rather than a replacement BLU device, and buy something more reputable. 20 years of privacy sanctions from the Federal Trade Commission mean they found something pretty bad in BLU's organisation.